# 24 VAC and its role in a control board

Tags: pcb, transformer, voltage-divider

I was looking at a circuit/control board of [COMMERCIAL/INDUSTRIAL CONTINUOUS DUTY BELT DRIVE APARTMENT TROLLEY OPERATOR](https://micanan.com/en/product/pro-apt) and came across 24 VAC in multiple places (both in [Hard-Wire and Circuit Board sections](https://micanan.com/en/support/files?category=34)). My recollection of 24 VAC is that it is used to relay or switch to break contact. I am trying to understand what is it in charge of in this specific trolley.

I am afraid this may be a very broad/complicated question, but I hope my question it is clear. Please let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: the usage is probably for control purposes, similar to HVAC

Comment: thanks! do you mind taking a look into the diagrams? I would appreciate if you could outline most critical items? I can see 24 VAC is used with reversing relay. Would be interested to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

24Vac low power is historically common for industrial relay coils , furnaces and “Nice” rolling trolley relay logic with sensor switches.

Answer (score 1):

From a theoretical perspective, any voltage could be used as a control voltage. That said, there are many practical implications that must be considered, not the least of which being safety--both of the the equipment and the people interacting with it. In general, the lower the voltage, the higher the safety level. It would follow that the ideal voltage level for an application would be the lowest voltage for which the required power can practically be delivered to the load.

In general, 24vac is of a low enough voltage to ensure personnel safety, but high enough to perform the necessary work of a control circuit (powering electronics, driving relay coils/solenoids, etc.). It is also high enough to support minor voltage drops over cabling to field connected devices.

Not sure of your jurisdiction, but in the US, NFPA 70 has different requirements for what it defines as Class 1, Class 2 and Class 3 circuits. For Class 2 and 3 circuits, 3 ac voltage categories are considered: 0 through 20V, 20 through 30V, and 30 through 150V. As you can see, the use of a 24Vac control circuit would fall into the 20-30V category and it’s associated requirements, which could be the deciding factor over the more stringent requirements of, say, 120Vac.